# I want to check last sent parameters against the new parameters sent in method, everytime a method is called in c#

Tags: c#, parameters, parameter-passing

This is my method below which actively gets data from the instrument, i want to check the new parameters sent with last parameters everytime this method is called

```
 public bool SampleQueueChanged(  int samplesRemainingInQueue, int injectionsRemainingInQueue)
```

can anyone please help with it?  or show  a right way

Comment: Could you be more precise as which parameters you're trying to check against which and what are you trying to check exactly ?

Comment: i want to  check the value of  samplesRemainingInQueue in greater or lesser than its previous value, when this method is called

Comment: Does your application have many threads? If so this is going to cause race conditions.

Comment: @gunr2171 yeah, we have multi process working. can you suggest any alternatives, where i can differentiate the values ?

Comment: Just save the old value in a member of the class and before resave it check it against its new value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question could probably use more clarification. From what I understand you want to compare the current parameters with the parameters from the last call.

Typically you would create a private variable to hold the value of the last call. Something like `private int _count` and so on.

It would be up to you as the writer of the method to do your comparison and overwrite the old variables with their current value.

Comment: can you help with initial value, will it be equal to zero or null?

Comment: @destroyer if you don't specify anything values like the integers will default to 0 and more complex classes and pointers will default to null.